# How to get the authentication provider which authenticated the current user in Firebase Authentication for Web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my web application users can choose between multiple authentication providers. The browser persists the authentication state, so that a user is already logged in after closing the browser and visiting the app later.

I can hook into `firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(...)` to get the user id and other stuff. But I can not find the authentication provider which was used by the user. I need to know whether it was Google-Authentication, Telephone-Authentication or what ever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more details about with which provider*s* the user is signed in by looking at the [`providerData` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#providerdata). This is an array, as a single account can be associated with multiple providers.

If a user account is associated with multiple providers, there is no way in the auth state listener to determine which provider they signed in with this time around as far as I know. You'll have to record that fact yourself by determining which `signInWith...` method you call in your application code.